# Método editar com problema no Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Criei um projeto em Spring Boot com ThymeLeaf e estou tendo problemas na implementação que faz atualização dos registros do banco, a aplicação está conseguindo salvar os registros, ele está conseguindo validar os campos agora somente falta acerta a implementação de edição de registros do banco.

Depois que consigo salvar os registros ele me dá uma tela de sucesso logo na parte superior da tela, e em seguida vou para a tela de listagem dos registro do banco como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico no icone de caneta para editar, ele retorna para tela de cadastro sendo com o dados nós campos recuperados para edição, sendo que na hora de submeter o formulário ele não consegue salvar, e na tela de edição também não conseguir validar os campos se caso haja um campo em brancos, como resolver isso?

Esse é o método de editar;

```
@RequestMapping("/pesquisa/{codigo}")
public ModelAndView edicao(@PathVariable("codigo") Boleto boleto) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("boleto/CadastroBoleto");
    mv.addObject(boleto);
    return mv;
}
```

na pagina pesquisa é essa parte;

```
<a class="btn btn-link btn-xs" th:href="@{/boleto/pesquisa/{codigo}(codigo=${boleto.codigo})}" 
                                       title="Editar" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                               </a>
```

Eu não estou vendo nada errado, eu até tentei usar o debug do Spring Boot, mas ele trava minha plataforma de desenvolvimento de uma maneira que fico incapaz de usa-lo.

o debug que estou me referindo seria no arquivo application.properties

```
logging.level.root=debug
```

Eu não sei se coloquei as parte que seriam necessárias para alguém me ajuda, então estou disponibilizando meu projeto completo para quem quiser tira dúvida e quiser ver outras parte que seja relevante para me ajudar no projeto.

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/boleto

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você já tenha conseguido resolver o problema. Caso não, para editar você está passando o ID do boleto, mas no controller você não pega esse id.

No meu projeto eu fiz da seguinte maneira e está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    return add(userService.findOne(id));

}
```